# How can I create a Holoviews dynamic map in a Dash callback function

Tags: python, plotly-dash, holoviews

Holoviews helps me a lot for plotting heatmap upon a huge dataset. Let's assume I made a simple function to generate a dynamic map:

```py
def gen_map(pd_df):
    points = hv.Points(df, [x, y])
    tiles = hv.Tiles().opts(mapboxstyle='dark', accesstoken=token)
    overlay = tiles * datashade(points)
    return overlay
```

I noticed that this `overlay` is a kind of `DynamicMap` instance. If I need to use this element in a Dash application, based on the doc, I should use `to_dash` function to transform this `DynamicMap` to a `DashComponents` instance (let's named it as `components`). Finally I just need to assign `components.children` to a `html.Div` element.

A simple script looks like

```py
overlay = gen_map(df)
components = to_dash(dash_app, [overlay])

app.layout = html.Div([components.children])
```

This works well when I generate this components out of the `app.callback` fucntion.
But if I tried to put such function in an `app.callback` function with some other conditions which provided by end users, the heatmap on the map is fixed. It can't zoom in to show more details with the map together.

The script structure looks like this:

```py
app.layout([
    dcc.DatePickrRange(id='date-range', start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date),
    html.Button('GO', id='go-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='for-fig')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('for-fig', 'children'),
    Input('go-buttion', 'n_clicks'),
    State('date-range', 'start_date'),
    State('date-range', 'end_date'),
)
def show_graph(n_clicks, start_date, end_date):
    # I need to use a callback to get a sub dataset
    dff = df.loc[(df.time > start_date) & (df.time < end_date)]

    # I found the grid would be fixed if I created a map in this callback function
    overlay = gen_map(dff)
    components = to_dash(dash_app, [overlay])
    return components.children
```

I found that if I referred a global `components` instance, it works well in the callback function, such as:

```py
components = gen_map(df)

@app.callback(...)
def show_graph(...):
    global components
    ...
    return components.children
```

But this will show the whole dataset rather than a sub dataset based on some customized conditions.

May I know the correct way to generate a dynamic Holoviews map in a Dash callback function, please? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: any chance you could put together a local [mre] with a small code-generated example dataset? this question lies at the intersection of a number of complex libraries - the number of people who could debug all of these at the same time in pseudocode isn't super high I imagine ;)

Comment: Thanks for the kind reminding. I'll improve my description soon :)